# save on model with nested attributes does not rollback, when autosave associations fails executing DDL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, ruby-on-rails-3.2, oracle-call-interface

Following are the class definition between the parent & child :-

```
class System
  has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :members
  attr_accessible :name, :members_attributes
  validates_presence_of :name , :members

class Member
   belongs_to :system
   attr_accessible  :name
   validates_presence_of :name
   before_create :create_physical_schema_for_user
```

In the controller I create the entire relationship in one go :-

```
@system = System.new(params[:system])
...
@system.save
```

Things are good until one of the before_create callbacks in the child fails with OCIError (raised by the ruby-oci8 gem) causing ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception. At this stage, the parent is saved even though one of the child association has not been saved. Am not sure, if this is an issue with rails or the oracle adapters.

Also FYI, create_physical_schema_for_user method runs a set of DDL's in the following fashion :-

```
def self.create_physical_schema_for_user(name)
  ddl_stmt = ['...',name]
  self.connection.execute(sanitize_sql(ddl_stmt))
end
```

I found these links where the same issue is being discussed (just that the callbacks differ)

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3391-nested-attributes-vs-before_save

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3045-nested_attributes-doesnt-rollback-parent-when-before_saveafter_save-callbacks-fail

One of them says that this has been merged in Rails 2, I still hit this issue in rails 3.2.5 but with Oracle Adapters

I wish to know what is the best way to inherently save the parent and all its associations in a single transaction, such that even if one child creation fails, we rollback the entire Parent transaction.

Environment :
Rails 3.2.5, Ruby 1.9.2

Database:
Oracle 11g XE through ruby-oci8 (2.1.2) & activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.1) gem

Comment: Have you tried it in a different database like sqlite to see if it's something funky with the Oracle adapter?

Comment: Thanks, you were right, happens only with Oracle Adapters. Not sure who is at fault. I have corrected the question with additional information on what am actually doing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure transactions will only rollback if the callback returns false such as when a CRUD operation fails. You could try rescuing from that ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid exception and just return false.

Comment: Ok, the reason why the transaction is not rolled back when the callback on one of the child fails, is because I am executing a bunch of DDL's in the callbacks.
As with Oracle & MySQL, DDL's autocommit the transaction in which they are executed. 
Now, I need to find a way to execute the DDL's in a session separate from the ActiveRecord's connection. I am trying to figure out a way to do it. Once I am done, I will update the answer.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html -- Caveats section clarifies my statement

Answer (score 1):

This whole issue would not have happened if I had not used DDL's in the callbacks - which autocommits the open transaction. Thus even if one of the DDL failed, the parent cannot be rolledback, since it would have been already committed.

I have done the following to execute the DDL's in a separate database connection, and hence their failure would not affect the Model's transaction and can be safely rolled back.

I defined a class to handle the DDL execution in a separate connection.

```
class SqlSystem  < ActiveRecord::Base
 establish_connection Rails.configuration.database_configuration[Rails.env]
 private
 def self.execute_ddl(stmt)
    self.connection.execute(sanitize_sql(stmt))
 end
end
```

and inside the before_create callback of the member class:-

```
def self.create_physical_schema_for_user(name)
  begin 
    SqlSystem.execute_ddl('...')
  rescue => error
    return false # Or Re-Raise the exception, whichever suits
  end
end
```

Note: I know its not the rails way to execute DDL's from ActiveRecord, but I am developing an application for DBA's to manage their production environment eg. Provisioning Users, Granting Privileges etc. And hence need to execute DDL's. I haven't found a better way to do it.